# Stuck comparing two values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a javascript remote for Kodi, where i only send data if it is changed. I am stuck with this peace of code. It will check every x seconds for a value but i only want to do something if the value has changed. Can someone shed some light on this?

```
every((0.35).second(), function() {
  var kodi_api_request = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "Player.GetActivePlayers", "id": 1};
  var kodi = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(kodi_api_request));
  var previous = {};
  var stuff = request
  .get('http://localhost:8080/jsonrpc?request=' + kodi, function (error, response, data) {
    var newdata = data
    if (previous !== newdata) {
      console.log('changed');
      previous = newdata;
      console.log(newdata);
    } else {
      console.log('Error!');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks like the data is a complex object, you'll have to check each property and see if equals.

Comment: Well, the object i am getting back is this: 

    {"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"playerid":1,"type":"video"}]}

Not too complex...

Comment: And you need to compare only the `.id` attribute, i.e. it's unique? If so just change to `if (previous.id !== newdata.id) {` would work.

Comment: I was just going to say, perhaps `id` would be sufficient, if it really is unique.

Comment: First, in order to save the preveious value, the variable `previous` must be global. You can achieve this like this :

    window.previous = {}; // must be done once before your function

Or, you can do this in you function :

    window.previous = window.previous || {}; // create it if it doesn't exists

Comment: @ikken wrong. The scope is just fine in the posted code sample, no need to make it part of window.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard . by declaring the variable `var previous = {};`  like in the post, it supposes that previous will be initialized every time the callback  of function `every` is called. So, the previous value will be lost

Comment: @ikken that's the whole point, that the previous value will be lost and overwritten with the current value. Unless I'm way off here and you can come with a proof I'm wrong, I can't see anything wrong with the scope.

Comment: All local variables of function `every((0.35).second(), function() {` are destroyed at the end of evry execution. So, nothing is saved for the next exeuction. It is the basic definition of local variables

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Comparison is working, however, the whole thing indeed gets executed every x seconds so it always will run the whole thing. This way it is not going to work.